# Can I shorthand chain divisibility in the same manner as equality?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, notation, divisibility

In the topic of divisibility. Suppose I starts with $a \mid n$, then I manipulate it into $a \mid m$, then $a \mid s$, and finally $a \mid t$. Should I write my train of thought as

$$
\begin{align}
a \mid n
&\implies a \mid m \\
&\implies a \mid s \\
&\implies a \mid t.
\end{align}
$$

Or can I just shorthanded it (in the same manner as equality) into

$$
\begin{align}
a
&\mid n \\
&\mid m \\
&\mid s \\
&\mid t.
\end{align}
$$

Can I do that? *Should* I do that? Anyone done that before?

Comment: This is just a matter of notation. If you think that your intended audience would be able to understand it (with help from the surrounding context), then you’re good to go.

Comment: $a \mid n \iff a \mid m$ just means that $n = m$.

Comment: I've never seen anyone do it before (and I hope I never see anyone do it again).

Comment: *Equivalence* ($\iff$) is usually wrong here. More often than not implication ($\implies$) is what you want. When you write $(a\mid n)\iff (a\mid m)$, you claim that $a$ divides $m$ whenever it divides $n$, **and conversely** $a$ divides $n$ whenever it divides $m$. But, like Greg, I'm happy with $a\mid m\mid n\mid t$, if all those divisibility relations hold. There are other occasions, when you can make deductions. For example, if $a$ is a prime number known to divide $n=mr$, where  we have extra information telling that $a\nmid r$, we can deduce that $a\mid m$.

Comment: Following up with J.-E. Pin's comment, if you are really manipulating $a\mid n$ into an equivalent $a\mid m$, then you often should just be showing $m=n$ or $m=-n$ directly, without the $a\mid$ in the way (however, maybe you have a special context like Jyrki mentioned; in that case, do you really need both directions of the implication?). As pointed out in the comments, showing a single directional implication rather than the bidirectional ones you've written would be a different context.

Comment: I think you are right. It should be $\implies$, not $\iff$.

Comment: @Mark, manipulating $a\mid n$ into an equivalent $a\mid m$ need not imply $m=\pm n$. I already gave the example $7\mid x+3$ is equivalent to $7\mid x+10$ where this does not imply $x+3=\pm(x+10)$.

Answer (score 2):

If it is the case that $a$ divides $n$ and $n$ divides $m$ and $m$ divides $s$ and $s$ divides $t$, then you can write $a\mid n\mid m\mid s\mid t$ and that's perfectly understandable. (Chaining like this really works for *transitive* binary relations.) But I wouldn't write this vertically as you've done in the second equation.

On the other hand, if you're proving that all of $n$, $m$, $s$, and $t$ are multiples of $a$ without saying that they divide one another, then the first way (with implication signs) seems reasonable.

Comment: I don't think OP is claiming each term divides the next. E.g., $7\mid x+3$ if and only if $7\mid x+10$, but $x+3$ doesn't (necessarily) divide $x+10$.

Comment: You have a point @Gerry, and the question is unclear. My gut feeling, too,  was that the expression *chain divisibility* in the title means using transitivity of "divides". Of course, there is little reason to think that the OP's choice of phrase would align with my intestines.